# Error downloading shinyapps from github

Tags: download, devtools, shiny

I'm trying to download the package shinyapps following the instructions given in:
http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/shinyapps.html

but I am having some errors.

I am on Windows 64 bit; my R version is R x64 3.2.1; my RStudio version is 0.99.447.

Here you can find the command I used:

```
if (!require("devtools"))
   install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("rstudio/shinyapps")
```

The `devtools` package seems correctly installed but I get the following error:

```
Downloading github repo rstudio/shinyapps@master
Installing shinyapps
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpsbU7D7/devtools112063ad32a2/rstudio-shinyapps-688a4ac"  \
  --library="\\someadress/R/win-library/3.2" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'shinyapps' ...
** R
** inst
** tests
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
Warning in library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE) :
  there is no package called 'shinyapps'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
Warning in library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE) :
  there is no package called 'shinyapps'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64'
* removing '\\someadress/Users/myname/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/shinyapps'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

I also tried to manually download the package from github (shinyapps-master.zip), unzip the folder and copy the folder into the R library folder. First of all the folder is not called shinyapps but shinyapps-master; I tried to call the library both as `shinyapps` and `shinyapps-master` but without success. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: By chance is your R library on a network drive?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem! Did you find a way to fix it?